# sudo easy_install bsddb3 error :Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation

Tags: python, berkeley-db, qgis, bsddb

I tried to make a plugin on qgis with Python 2.7.3

and there is a error happend
[image: images]

and I find a way to install **bsddb3** to replace bsddb

but when I try

```
$sudo easy_install bsddb3
```

it's give me a error

```
Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation
```

I have find a way that installed Homebrew and GCC can solve the problem

but after I install but error still happen

how I fix the problem?

here is i followed the steps on the

[Hacking OS X’s Python dbhash and bsddb modules to work](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/)

[2](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/)

[image]

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814041/how-to-fix-the-broken-bsddb-install-in-the-default-python-package-on-mac-os-x-10

Comment: yeah,I have tried that homepage's solution but I try to install bsddb3 the error happend....I even can't install bsddb3 at first it's need Berkeley DB,but I don't know how to install it

Comment: Perhaps it works better if you download bsddb3 (instead of using easy_install), usually you can edit `setup.py` to configure paths for local library/header locations). Download can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3/5.3.0).

Comment: http://imgur.com/cCREVPI it's just need berkely DB again....

Comment: Did you use the `--berkeley-db` option as suggested in the error message?

Comment: -bash: --berkeley-db=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db/5.3.21: No such file or directory it's give me this error I am so sure I have that directory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I got bsddb3 to work on my Mac.

First, download the Python module source (I used the `.tar.gz` version) from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bsddb3/5.3.0

Next, make sure BerkeleyDB is installed. I use MacPorts and installed the `db48` package. This places the includefiles in `/opt/local/include/db48` and the libraries in `/opt/local/lib/db48`. If you're using HomeBrew, those locations might be different.

Unpack `bsddb3` and install it using the correct paths:

```
python setup.py --berkeley-db-incdir=/opt/local/include/db48 --berkeley-db-libdir=/opt/local/lib/db48 install
```

After that, I had a working `bsddb3` package. You still need to patch modules which try to include `bsddb` and replace it with `bsddb3` instead.