# Installing bsddb package - python

Tags: python, macos, installation, package

I am totally new to python and I have this message when I try to import bsdddb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    import _bsddb
ImportError: No module named _bsddb
```

So I followed [this](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814041/how-to-fix-the-broken-bsddb-install-in-the-default-python-package-on-mac-os-x-10), so I downloaded this package `bsddb3-4.5.0.tar.gz`. What am I suppose to do with it, I tried to run python install setup.py int the bsddb3-4.5.0 in the right directory (I am using an osx). Then I get

```
Can't find a local BerkeleyDB installation.
(suggestion: try the --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb option)
```

Some one could help ?

Answer (score 20):

bsddb is [deprecated since 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bsddb.html#module-bsddb). The ideal is to use [the bsddb3 module](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm).

My suggestion, and by far the easiest option, is to install [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and use it to get BerkeleyDB on your system:

```
brew install berkeley-db
```

After this install bsddb3 using [pip](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

```
pip install bsddb3
```

or download the [source](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/bsddb3/bsddb3-5.3.0.tar.gz#md5=d5aa4f293c4ea755e84383537f74be82) and install normally.

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: pip install straight didn't quite work for me, I had to go to the source directory of bsddb3 and do a python setup.py install --berkeley-db=$(brew --prefix)/berkeley-db/5.3.21/

Comment: Looks like it might have moved again in brew, expanding on Chmouel's comment: 
`python setup.py install --berkeley-db=\`find $(brew --prefix)/*/berkeley-db/5* -name berk*\``

Comment: This worked for me on Mavericks using `python` from Apple and `pip` and `berkeley-db` from Homebrew (as root): `BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db/5.3.28 pip install bsddb3` (for details see http://chriszf.posthaven.com/getting-berkeleydb-working-with-python-on-osx)

Comment: Update for 2016: `YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=1 BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db/6.1.26 pip install bsddb3`, which worked for me.

Comment: Update for 2018: 
OSX El Capitan introduces "System Integrity Protection" which means root is no longer "God" and some system directories are simply unwritable. Problem: built-in python's `pip` tries to write to one of these sacred directories so it no longer works. SO, first install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and run: `pip install python`. After that, open a new terminal window and you can continue as normal:

`sudo YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=1 BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db/6.2.32 pip install bsddb3`

Comment: `bsddb3` is now `berkleydb`: `YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=1 BERKELEYDB_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/berkeley-db/18.1.40 pip install berkeleydb`

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue but none of the suggestions worked for me as I couldn't use AGPL license or a commercial Berkeley license from Oracle.

```
BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db/6.1.26 pip install bsddb3
Collecting bsddb3
Using cached bsddb3-6.1.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Trying to use the Berkeley DB you specified...
Detected Berkeley DB version 6.1 from db.h

******* COMPILATION ABORTED *******

You are linking a Berkeley DB version licensed under AGPL3 or have a commercial license.

AGPL3 is a strong copyleft license and derivative works must be equivalently licensed.

You have two choices:

  1. If your code is AGPL3 or you have a commercial Berkeley DB license from Oracle, please, define the environment variable 'YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION' to any value, and try to install this python library again.

  2. In any other case, you have to link to a previous version of Berkeley DB. Remove Berlekey DB version 6.x and let this python library try to locate an older version of the Berkeley DB library in your system. Alternatively, you can define the environment variable 'BERKELEYDB_DIR', or 'BERKELEYDB_INCDIR' and 'BERKELEYDB_LIBDIR', with the path of the Berkeley DB you want to use and try to install this python library again.

Sorry for the inconvenience. I am trying to protect you.

More details:

    https://forums.oracle.com/message/11184885
    http://lists.debian.org/debian-legal/2013/07/

******* COMPILATION ABORTED *******
```

However reverting to an older version fixed it.

Install the older version of berkeley-db with brew

`brew install berkeley-db4`

Then as suggested install bsddb3 with pip

`pip install bsddb3`

Then

`BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db4/4.8.30 pip install bsddb3`

(modified from Stefan Schmidt's comment to reference the older berkeley-db [version](http://brewformulas.org/Berkeley-db4) directory)

Finally apply patch to dbhash.py as described [here](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/).

Answer (score 7):

@bamdan 's answer uses an older version of Berkeley DB, if you still want to use the latest, Berkeley DB,

- First, install the latest Berkeley DB

  ```
  pip install berkeley-db
  ```
- Second, set an environment variable `YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION` to indicate that you have the license

  ```
  BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --cellar)/berkeley-db4/6.1.26 YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=yes pip install bsddb3
  ```

Comment: Version agnostic version: `BERKELEYDB_DIR=$(brew --prefix berkeley-db) YES_I_HAVE_THE_RIGHT_TO_USE_THIS_BERKELEY_DB_VERSION=yes pip install bsddb3`

Comment: I think you meant to type `brew install berkeley-db`. Also, what is the deal with this license? How do I know I have this right?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something that is currently missing, I'm a Linux Ubuntu/Debian user, but I have to make my python scripts work on macOS systems. I encountered the same issue that user1611830 encountered.

I followed the steps explained by Francisco Roque and Sean above. However, I was obtaining the same initial problem. I saw Bamdan's answer and wanted to see the patch he referred to modify dbhash.py using the link he provided [source](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/). But the 'patch' link is no longer working.

I found out that in order to modify dbhash.py as explained in [source](http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2007/11/28/hacking-os-xs-python-dbhash-and-bsddb-modules-to-work/), one needs to disable the System Integrity Protection, so followed the instructions of this answer [disablingSIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294609/cannot-change-permissions-on-system-library). Afterward, I could modify dbhash.py and the new bsddb3 worked and I could use shelve to read in workspaces saved previously.