# How to fix "Can't find local Berkeley DB" error?

Tags: python, scrapy, virtualenv, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install scrapy-deltafetch in a virtual-environment (as described [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)) on my new raspberry pi 3 with Raspbian.

When I'm running `pip install scrapy-deltafetch` in my virtualenv, I'm getting something like this:

> python setup.py egg_info:
>   Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ib6d93/bsddb3/

However when I'm running `sudo pip install scrapy-deltafetch` outside of my virtual-environment everything works fine.

Does anybody has an idea of how to install scrapy-deltafetch in the virtualenvironment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your system is missing Berkeley DB, which is used by DeltaFetch to store requests data.

So, first install Berkeley DB in your system (found [this tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/server/db.html) in a quick search).

After that, you have to install the `bsddb3` Python package (you can follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213338/1084647)).

**Edit (2020):**

This should work:

```
$ sudo apt install libdb-dev
$ pip install bsddb3
```

Answer (score 10):

In case of my Ubuntu 18.04 missing system library is called [libdb-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdb-dev).

```
> sudo apt-get install libdb-dev
```

This fixed the problem for me.