# I am trying to install bsddb3, but there is an error, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pip, installation, berkeley-db

I write in the console:

```
pip3 install bsddb3
```

But I get the error:

```
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/fc/ebfbd4de236b493f9ece156f816c21df0ae87ccc22604c5f9b664efef1b9/bsddb3-6.2.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Can't find a local Berkeley DB installation.
    (suggestion: try the --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb option)
```

Wrote after:python -m pip install bsddb --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb

```
Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /usr/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /usr/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /usr/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /usr/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...
  no such option: --berkeley-db
```

Comment: Same question was asked check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17213338)

Comment: @abdoulsn, I'm use linux ubuntu, for me doen't worked.

Comment: you know where is berkeley-db location ?

Comment: @temmo, no. You think the wrong position?

Comment: maybe add `python -m pip install bsddb --berkeley-db=/path/to/bsddb`

Comment: @temmo, doesn't work. Console wrote in question

Comment: @ArtemSh HAVE YOU INSTAll the bsddb in your ubuntu machine ? also if not then [download bsddb3 tar file](https://pypi.org/project/bsddb3/6.2.6/) and unzip and follow the readme instruction

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu systems (as OP is using Ubuntu), you need to install the `libdb++-dev` package and then `bsddb3` python package installs fine:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev
export BERKELEYDB_DIR=/usr
pip3 install bsddb3
```

Comment: It works on kali.

Comment: Thank you - these steps are also required on Debian Bullseye (on pi)